# Oracle19c container cannot startup after turning on archive log

Tags: oracle, docker, containers

I'm running oracle19c container.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  oracle:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0
    container_name: oracle19c
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - oracle19c:/opt/oracle/oradata
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    shm_size: '2gb'
networks:
  oracle19c:
    external: yes
volumes:
  oracle19c:
    external: yes
```

Everything works fine before I turning on the archivelog.

```
sqlplus sys / as sysdba

SQL> shutdown immediate;
    Database closed.
    Database dismounted.
    ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup mount;
    ORACLE instance started.

SQL> alter database archivelog;
    Database altered.

SQL> alter database open;
    Database altered.
```

Then the Database is down and I cannot start it any more, this is the docker logs:

```
[root@ATM-6601509-10 oracle_19c]# docker logs oracle19c -f
[2023:05:28 18:35:27]: Acquiring lock .ORCLCDB.create_lck with heartbeat 30 secs
[2023:05:28 18:35:27]: Lock acquired
[2023:05:28 18:35:27]: Starting heartbeat
[2023:05:28 18:35:27]: Lock held .ORCLCDB.create_lck
ORACLE EDITION: ENTERPRISE

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:35:27 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 1 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:35:33 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 2 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:35:39 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 3 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:35:46 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 4 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:35:54 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 5 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:36:03 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 6 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:36:13 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 7 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:36:24 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 8 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:36:36 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 9 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:36:49 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> Disconnected
Waiting for 10 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Releasing lock .ORCLCDB.create_lck
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Lock released .ORCLCDB.create_lck
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Acquiring lock .ORCLCDB.exist_lck with heartbeat 30 secs
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Lock acquired
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Starting heartbeat
[2023:05:28 18:37:04]: Lock held .ORCLCDB.exist_lck

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 28-MAY-2023 18:37:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ed39669f3ec6/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                28-MAY-2023 18:37:04
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ed39669f3ec6/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:04 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 1 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:09 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 2 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:15 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 3 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:22 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 4 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:31 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 5 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:40 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 6 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:37:50 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 7 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:38:01 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 8 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:38:13 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 9 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 18:38:26 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL>    alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter pluggable database all open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL>    alter system register
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
Waiting for 10 sec(s) before restarting Oracle processes and opening the database
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
#####################################
########### E R R O R ###############
DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
Please check output for further info!
########### E R R O R ###############
#####################################
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
tail: cannot open '/opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/*/*/trace/alert*.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

This seems that oracle19c is looking for the init file initORCLCDB.ora.

Actually, inside the docker, there is no initORCLCDB.ora file.

```
[root@ATM-6601509-10 oracle_19c]# docker exec -it oracle19c bash
bash-4.2$ cd /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/
bash-4.2$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba        67 May 28 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba        60 May 28 18:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba      3079 May 14  2015 init.ora
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall   49 May 28 17:23 orapwORCLCDB -> /opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/ORCLCDB/orapwORCLCDB
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall   54 May 28 17:23 spfileORCLCDB.ora -> /opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/ORCLCDB/spfileORCLCDB.ora
```

I'm not sure why it's looking for that initORCLCDB.ora file. Because, by default there is no that initORCLCDB.ora file inside the docker (I created the new docker in other server and check it, no that file at all).

I tried to startup database with severals options, but it's still failed:

```
[root@ATM-6601509-10 oracle_19c]# docker-compose up -d
WARNING: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: oracle19c
Starting oracle19c ... done
[root@ATM-6601509-10 oracle_19c]# docker exec -it oracle19c bash
bash-4.2$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 28 20:16:13 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> shutdown;
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4376
Additional information: 1135834575
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> startup spfile=/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora;
SP2-0714: invalid combination of STARTUP options
```

When I create pfile from existing sfile, it's still failed:

```
SQL> create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora';
create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
Additional information: 1
```

This is the content of spfileORCLCDB.ora:

```
C"▒▒f▒▒CCC"["ORCLCDB.__data_transfer_cache_size=0
ORCLCDB.__db_cache_size=889192448
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_roarea=0
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_rwarea=0
ORCLCDB.__java_pool_size=0
ORCLCDB.__large_pool_size=67108864
ORCLCDB.__oracle_base='/opt/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
ORCLCDB.__pga_aggregate_target=536870912
ORCLCDB.__sga_target=1610612736
ORCLCDB.__shared_io_pool_size=83886080
ORCLCDB.__shared_pool_size=520093696
ORCLCDB.__streams_pool_size=33554432
ORCLCDB.__unified_pga_pool_size=0
*.CC"v9audit_file_dest='/opt/oracle/admin/ORCLCDB/adump'
*.audit_sys_operations=false
*.audit_trail='none'
*.compatible='19.0.0'
*.control_files='/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/control01.ctl'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_flashback_retention_target=1440
*.db_name='ORCLCDB'
*.diagnostic_dest='/opt/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLCDBXDB)'
*.enable_pluggable_database=true
*.CC":)local_listener=''
*.log_archive_format='%s_%t_%r.ARC'
*.log_archive_start=TRUE
*.nls_language='AMERICAN'
*.nls_territory='AMERICA'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=512m
*.processes=640
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=1536m
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
CC"FeCC"EeCC"DeC
```

Please help me how to fix this, it already has data in mounted volume, I need to keep the data.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your spfile appears to be corrupted. Did you attempt to edit it directly with anything that would have changed its content or size?

Comment: Spfile is a binary file originally, but your spfile looks like a mix of binary spfile with inserted text records from pfile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was originally configured to start with `spfile`, but after your changes it tries to start with `pfile`.

So you can either create pfile:
`create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile;`

or you can try to find your startup script and check if it uses `startup pfile...` and fix it to start with spfile (just remove `pfile` clause,  oracle uses spfile by default).

**Update:**

After your additions, I'd suggest you to rename your current spfile and create a correct one:

1. create pfile - run in bash:

```
cat >/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora <<EOF
*.audit_file_dest='/opt/oracle/admin/ORCLCDB/adump'
*.audit_sys_operations=false
*.audit_trail='none'
*.compatible='19.0.0'
*.control_files='/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/control01.ctl'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_flashback_retention_target=1440
*.db_name='ORCLCDB'
*.diagnostic_dest='/opt/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLCDBXDB)'
*.enable_pluggable_database=true
*.CC":)local_listener=''
*.log_archive_format='%s_%t_%r.ARC'
*.log_archive_start=TRUE
*.nls_language='AMERICAN'
*.nls_territory='AMERICA'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=512m
*.processes=640
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=1536m
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
EOF
```

2. create spfile from this pfile:

```
create spfile from pfile;
```

Comment: Even I start without pfile, it stills error: SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'

Comment: I tried to create pfile, but it errors: SQL> create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora';
create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
Additional information: 1

Comment: @MiH check the update